# All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I have checked my app build.gradle file and these are the only lines that are related to firebase in them

```
/***
 * Firebase
 */
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'
```

I do not have any library that makes use of firebase so I don't think there can be an issue with a library using an older version.

The problem is I can't build gradle, clean project or rebuild project with the new v15 version of firebase as it keeps throwing the error `All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0`

Comment: can you show us ur build.gradle+  did u add the apply plugin line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to change the version number for `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads`, switched it to `15.0.0` and it worked.

Here's a blog by Google that provides more information.
[Announcing new SDK versioning in Google Play services and Firebase](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html?m=1)

Comment: Great, didn't realize there were additional dependencies on other play-services plugins to match the version of the firebase plugin.

Answer (score 19):

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

put it under this line.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

it worked for me.

Comment: it doesn't make any kind of sense 
But it worked for me thank you !! saved my day

Comment: thanks, worked for me too... But, I must ask to google: why?

Answer (score 2):

I have not found the question yet in your question
But if you want the latest version of Firebys offices
This is compatible with version 27.0.3

```
//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from App level gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
```

and then try these versions

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

this one worked for me... tanx

Answer (score 0):

Change to this work for me:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
```

Try to find anything above 14.0.0 like:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
```

and try to change it to older version like

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

For example change 
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'` 
to 
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'`
, as this suggestion comes in the warning in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2` so that it's the same version as my `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2` library.

The change was in file `platform/android/project.properties`.

The location and push notifications library is working perfect now

Answer (score 0):

Change all of your firebase libraries to the same version.

Answer (score 0):

While Changing google or firebase dependency version make sure you update the compatible version in project level gradle too.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and changing the versions solved it:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

Hope this helps