# Error:(42, 0) All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

Tags: java, android, firebase

> Error:(42, 0) All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

when I put

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834694/all-firebase-libraries-must-be-either-above-or-below-14-0-0)

Answer (score 1):

In **build.gradle** change `firebase-ui:0.6.2` to `firebase-ui:3.3.1`

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.3.1'
```